# How to use the R 'with' operator in rpy2

Tags: python, r, logistic-regression, rpy2, ordinal

I am doing an ordinal logistic regression, and following the guide here for the analysis: [R Data Analysis Examples: Ordinal Logistic Regression](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm)

My dataframe (consult) looks like:

```
           n  raingarden  es_score  consult_case
garden_id                                       
27436      7           0         3             0
27437      1           0         0             1
27439      1           1         1             1
37253      1           0         3             0
37256      3           0         0             0
```

I am at the part where I need to  to create graph to test the proportional odds assumption, with the command in R as follows:

```
(s <- with(dat, summary(es_score ~ n + raingarden + consult_case, fun=sf)))
```

(es_score is an ordinal ranked score with values between 0 - 4; n is an integer; raingarden and consult_case, binary values of 0 or 1)

I have the sf function:

```
sf <- function(y) {
     c('Y>=1' = qlogis(mean(y >= 1)),
       'Y>=2' = qlogis(mean(y >= 2)),
       'Y>=3' = qlogis(mean(y >= 3)))
}
```

in a utils.r file that I access as follows:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
with open('/file_path/utils.r', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()
sf = STAP(string, "sf")
```

And want to do something along the lines of:

```
R = ro.r
R.with(work_case_control, R.summary(formula, fun=sf))
```

The major problem is that the R `with`operator is seen as a python keyword, so that even if I access it with `ro.r.with` it is still recognized as a python keyword. (As a side note: I tried using R's `apply` method instead, but got an error that `TypeError: 'SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage' object is not callable` ... I assume this is referring to my function `sf`?)

I also tried using the R assignment methods in rpy2 as follows:

```
R('sf = function(y) { c(\'Y>=1\' = qlogis(mean(y >= 1)), \'Y>=2\' = qlogis(mean(y >= 2)), \'Y>=3\' = qlogis(mean(y >= 3)))}')

R('s <- with({0}, summary(es_score~raingarden + consult_case, fun=sf)'.format(consult))
```

but ran into issues where the dataframe column names were somehow causing the error: `RRuntimeError: Error in (function (file = "", n = NULL, text = NULL, prompt = "?", keep.source = getOption("keep.source"),  : 
  <text>:1:19: unexpected symbol
1: s <- with(      n raingarden`

I could of course do this all in R, but I have a very involved ETL script in python, and would thus prefer to keep everything in python using rpy2 (I did try this using mord for scipy-learn to run my regreession, but it is pretty primitive).

Any suggestions would be most welcome right now.

**EDIT**

I tried various combinations @Parfait's suggestions, and qualifying the `fun` argument is syntactically incorrect, as per PyCharm interpreter (see image with red highlighting at end): [image: with qualified fun keyword] ... it doesn't matter what the qualifier is, either, I always get an error
that `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression.`

On the other hand, with no qualifier, there is no syntax error: [image: unqualified fun keyword], but I do get the error `TypeError: 'SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage' object is not callable` when using the function `sf` as obtained:

`from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
with open('/Users/gregsilverman/development/python/rest_api/rest_api/scripts/utils.r', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()
sf = STAP(string, "sf")`

With that in mind, I created a package in R with the function `sf`, imported it, and tried various combos with the only one producing no error, being: `print(base._with(consult_case_control, R.summary(formula, fun=gms.sf)))` (gms is a reference to the package in R I made).

The output though makes no sense:

`Length   Class    Mode
      3 formula    call`

I am expecting a table ala the one on the UCLA site. Interesting. I am going to try recreating my analysis in R, just for the heck of it. I still would like to complete it in python though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider bracketing the `with` call and be sure to qualify all arguments including *fun*:

```
ro.r['with'](work_case_control, ro.r.summary(formula, ro.r.summary.fun=sf))
```

Alternatively, import R's base package. And to avoid conflict with Python's named method `with()` translate the R name:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base', robject_translations={'with': '_with'})

base._with(work_case_control, ro.r.summary(formula, ro.r.summary.fun=sf))
```

And be sure to properly create your formula. Consider using R's stats packages' `as.formula` to build from string. Notice too another translation is made due to naming conflict:

```
stats = importr('stats', robject_translations={'format_perc': '_format_perc'})

formula = stats.as_formula('es_score ~ n + raingarden + consult_case')
```

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I thought there had to be a way to use a keyword like this, although I do like the other solutions better. I did try these, and am getting an error on the qualified `fun` argument: `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression.`

It may take some experimentation, so I will play around with this.

Comment: What package is *summary*? If base R, try qualifying function and *fun* arg with `base` object and not `ro.r`.

Comment: I don't think `fun` needs a qualifier. In PyCharm, ANY qualifier there throws a highlighted red syntax error, while no qualifier colors `fun` syntactically correct as purple (I would attach images here, but cannot in comments).

Thus, I believe the statement should look like: `base._with(work_case_control, R.summary(formula, fun=sf))` ... and I believe the error that I am getting now: `NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.robjects.packages.SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage'>'` is referring to my implementation of the `sf` function in R.

Comment: I am editing my original post, since it is easier to format output there.

Comment: I just ran the analysis in R, and I get the same output! So, something else is amuck. I will accept your answer, since I definitely have made progress. I will no doubt post a few questions, although I'm wondering what a better forum is for this, StackOverflow or CrossValidated. My question was more on use of the tools versus methodology, but it is starting to evolve more into algorithm and expected output.

Comment: Interestingly, I found this thread, which was rather helpful (I was missing the `Hmisc` package): stackoverflow.com/questions/40575573/… ... I should have imported this package anyway as per the UCLA page (Mea culpa!). I am now getting the table printing in R, but an error when I try it in rpy2 about RRuntimeError: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'es_score' not found. I'll probably move this to a new question after I dig in a bit deeper. I will assume StackOverflow is still appropriate, since it seems to be related to the tool set.